# Behavior of polar coordinates under a diffeomorphism

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a compact and starshaped set with a smooth boundary. Furthermore we assume that the barycentre of $\Omega$ is $0$ and $|\Omega| = |B_1(0)|$. Then it is possible to represent the boundary $\partial \Omega$ in polar coordinates. For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\zeta\in \Sigma$ (the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$) these coordinates are give via
$$
|x| = 1 + u(\zeta).
$$

Now let $\Phi$ be a volume preserving diffeomorphism. Consider the set $\Phi(\Omega)$ and lets assume $\Phi(\Omega)$ is still a compact and starshaped set. My Question now is how do the polar coordinates for the boundary change under such a diffeomorphism? For example are the new polar coordinates give by
$$
|y|=1 + u(\Phi(\zeta)),
$$
with $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I think that the answer is negative for trivial reasons; if $\Phi$ is a translation then the boundary is not given by $|y|=1+u\circ\Phi(\zeta)$. But if you require that $\Phi$ fixes the origin, then it should be true.

Comment: yeah the barycenter should be fixed a $0$.